# Can a proxy server redirect traffic to malicious websites or modify downloads?

Tags: proxy

I was wondering if a proxy server from the internet could redirect traffic to malicious websites or download malware or even modify downloads( I do not plan on using a proxy server i found from the internet just wondering )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy servers can modify both request and response in arbitrary ways, can connect to different systems instead of the requested ones etc. This also includes manipulating downloads or manipulating responses so that the browser gets redirected. And this is not just theoretical but actually happens in practice, i.e. proxies injecting ads, injecting malware etc.

This is especially true for plain HTTP connections. For HTTPS connections this will not work as long as the browser properly checks the certificates (which it usually does) and the user does not skip over certificate warnings and of course if the users system is not already compromised. But note that the proxy might already intercept some initial plain HTTP connections which originally would redirect to the HTTPS site and could redirect the user instead to a similar looking HTTPS site under the proxies control.

For more see [“Free” Proxies Aren’t Necessarily Free](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/06/free-proxies-arent-necessarily-free/#more-31322) from 2015 or a more recent paper [An Extensive Evaluation of the Internet’s Open Proxies](https://security.cs.georgetown.edu/~msherr/papers/openproxies.pdf).

Comment: So if someone is visiting a website using a open proxy the person behind that proxy could inject malware into downloads and download malware onto a system or even redirecting to a phishing site or am i not understanding

Comment: @Joe: yes, that's what I'm exactly saying: *"Proxy servers can __modify__ both request and response __in arbitrary ways__, can connect to different systems instead of the requested ones etc. This also includes __manipulating downloads__ or manipulating responses so that the browser gets __redirected__. And this is not just theoretical but actually happens in practice, i.e. proxies __injecting ads, injecting malware__ etc."